# Is there an equivalent to the Matlab figure window in Python (with all tools)?

Tags: python, plot, window, matlab-figure

I'm just wondering if it exists an equivalent to the Matlab figure window in Python where we can modify plots directly from the figure window, or add some features (text, box , arrow, and so on), or make curve fitting, etc.

Matplotlib is good, but it is not as high-level as the Matlab figure. We need to code everything and if we want to modify plots, we need to modify the code directly (except for some basic stuffs like modifing the line color)

Comment: try looking into matplotlib

Comment: Yes I did. As mention in my question : Matplotlib is good, but it is not as high-level as the Matlab figure. Maybe it exists another module with more features I can modify in plot window  itself.

Answer (score 0):

With matplotlib, you will indeed remain in the "code it all" workflow. This is not *directly* the answer you expect but the matplotlib documentation recently gained a very instructive figure that will probably help you if you stay with matplotlib: http://matplotlib.org/examples/showcase/anatomy.html shows the "anatomy" of the figure with all the proper designations for the parts of the figure.

Overall, I could always find examples of what I needed in their excellent gallery http://matplotlib.org/gallery.html

In my opinion, you'll save time by coding these customizations instead of doing them by hand. You may indeed feel otherwise but if not there is a ton of examples of matplotlib code on SO, in their docs and a large community of people around it :-)

Comment: Thanks for answering. I know we can do a lot of things with Matplotlib, or other module like Bokeh and Pyqtgraph for instance. My concern is that it takes often some time to code what we want right. Sometime it is just for adding a text box, or whatever, in a figure I saved with pickle. In this condition is really a pain to add stuff into the figure. In Matlab, it is easy because the window allows a lot of modifications.  For now I use inkscape when I need to add basic things into my python figure, but it is kind of inconvenient to use two software.